# How to get primary key in Entity Framework for a new entry and set FK Relationship

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 application, I have situation where I need to get the primary key that got generated for a particular entry in database. Also, I need to get that id and set a foreign key relationship in database. I have tried below attempt and it seems to be working but I had to call `_context.SaveChanges()` TWICE.

UI Behaviour: the user has a dropdown with a list of companies in referral form. When a company is not found, user will select "Others" in the dropdown. And it will show a textbox, where user will enter the company name. So I need to add this company to the database and link it to the referral row.

Relationship between tables `Referral` and `Company`:

```
 dBModelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasMany(u => u.Referrals)
            .WithRequired(u => u.Company)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.CompanyId);
```

Model classes:

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Referral> Referrals { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CoverLetter> CoverLetters { get; set; }
}

public class Referral
{
    [Key]
    public int ReferralId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "REFERRALS")]
    public string ReferralName { get; set; }

    public int? CoverLetterId { get; set; }
    public virtual CoverLetter CoverLetter { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Referral
{
    [Key]
    public int ReferralId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "REFERRALS")]
    public string ReferralName { get; set; }

    public int? CoverLetterId { get; set; }
    public virtual CoverLetter CoverLetter { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

My attempt inside the controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(ReferralViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var candidateId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var referral = new Referral
        {
            ReferralName = viewModel.ReferralName,
        };

        if (viewModel.CompanyId.HasValue)
        // if it is option 4 then we need to add it to the company table
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.TempCompany))
            {
                var f = new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = viewModel.TempCompany
                };

                _context.Companies.Add(f);
               // ********FIRST CALL
                 _context.SaveChanges(); 

                _context.Referrals.Add(referral);
                 referral.CompanyId = f.CompanyId;
               // **********SECOND CALL
                _context.SaveChanges(); // SECOND CALL ------
            }
            else
            {
                referral.CompanyId = viewModel.CompanyId.Value;
                _context.Referrals.Add(referral);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ReferralCenter");
    }
```

Question: can I do these steps in one call to `_context.SaveChanges();` ?

**EDIT**

With this code, I get a `NullReferenceException`:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.TempCompany))
{
    var f = new Company
                {
                    CompanyName = viewModel.TempCompany
                };

    f.Referrals.Add(referral); // Referrals is NULL(EXCEPTION)
    _context.Companies.Add(f);
    // _context.SaveChanges();
    //_context.Referrals.Add(referral);
    // referral.CompanyId = f.CompanyId;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Which table is the Parent and which is the Child? Also, in your use case, you have a referral screen and then need to assign a company to that referral, where the Company may or may not exist in the DB?

Comment: I added the Fluent Api relationship in the question. Edited it.

Comment: @MrSlim: Yes, and when it does not exist user selects a so called "Company" called "Others" (which is itself a row in company table) and put the actual company name in textbox

Comment: @MrSlim: I added my entire controller action now. Can you kindly see it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that FK constraints are managed within EF, so long as they are configured in the DB.

If in your EF model the Referral is a child of Company then there should be a referrals collection accessible from the Company object instance.

**UPDATE**
I just built a simple sample MVC Proj, 2x SQL tables (Referrals and Company FK on CompanyId) 4 x Companies, 4th being OTHER, built an EF model with Reverse POCO for speed, added a Controller with scaffolding and views and modified my controller to the below. (I just insert the date time rather than tempCompanyName. The syntax generated here is more like that in the answer by @ashin, but it works for me.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReferralId,CompanyId")] Referral referral)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (referral.CompanyId == 4)
            {
                var f = new Company() { Name = DateTime.Now.ToString() };
                referral.Company = f;
            }
            db.Referrals.Add(referral);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.CompanyId = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyId", "Name", referral.CompanyId);
        return View(referral);
    }
```

My Company model does instanciate a new Referrals Collection

```
    public Company()
    {
        Referrals = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Referral>();
    }
```

Comment: Kindly see my " Problem" section in the question

Comment: I get NULL Refernce exception with your code. Kindly see my edit.

Comment: Do, I need to initialize referrals collection in constructor of company or something like that?

Comment: I did not have anything in the constructor of the company I just now added the constructor and now it works. So does that mean when ever I am setting a MANY Relationship I should always initialize the collection in the constructor as thumb rule?.

Comment: It has to be initialised somewhere, and I think the constructor seems an appropriate place. While understanding how EF configuration works is important, for sheer speed of getting something up and running I have been using Simon Hughes Reverse Poco Generator for years, Using this provides a uniform way in which your EF boilerplate code is generated. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator

Comment: I will look into that link. Thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the navigation property defined, you could just save both the Company and Referral in one shot as follows:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.TempCompany))
{
   var f = new Company
   {
        CompanyName = viewModel.TempCompany
   };
   referral.Company = f;
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

EF will take care of setting the FK.

**EDIT**

Have updated the code to include `_context.Referrals.Add(referral)` as mentioned in the comments:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.TempCompany))
{
   var f = new Company
   {
        CompanyName = viewModel.TempCompany
   };

   referral.Company = f;
   _context.Referrals.Add(referral);
   _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Kindly see my " Problem" section in the question

Comment: Ef sets the FK as  PK of "other" (row value) of company table

Comment: I believe this code would work if _context.Referrals.Add(referral) was called, so +1 for that

Comment: I saw the initial version of the question and it was very minimal. I was under the assumption that the `referral` object was already loaded by the context. Have edited my answer to include the change mentioned by Slim. Thanks! :)